# How to enqueue scripts on custom post add/edit pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, hooks, wp-enqueue-script, actions

I'm trying to enqueue a JS script only when someone is adding or editing a custom post type I created called "recipes". Currently the script works ok when I do this:

```
if (is_admin()){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
}
```

But this loads it in every admin page, I'm assuming I need to hook it to a function but I hvae no idea what it'd be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For future use, a similar question was answered with what I feel was an easier way: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/34894/93169

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do it like this (put in your `functions.php`) :

```
function add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {

    global $post;

    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        if ( 'recipes' === $post->post_type ) {     
            wp_enqueue_script(  'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/myscript.js' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Can i also enqueue style using this function?

Comment: @Sisir Use the `"admin_print_styles-{$page}"` hook. `$page` can hold the complete `add_(sub)menu_page()` code and be used to then target the page when using [`@see wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Comment: A more up to date way of doing this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/34897/93169 (also happens to be a little easier thanks to functionality changes in wordpress...)

Answer (score -3):

There's a hook for that, and it's dead-simple to use. [See this tutorial for an example implementation](http://devpress.com/blog/how-to-load-javascript-in-the-wordpress-admin/).

#### Edit

Justin moved his tutorials from DevPress to his personal site. [Here's the updated link for the tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/07/12/how-to-load-javascript-in-the-wordpress-admin).

Comment: The page listed is gone. Here's a mirror/archive on the [Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20110725035341/http://devpress.com/blog/how-to-load-javascript-in-the-wordpress-admin/).

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated my answer with a current link.

Comment: Why not post the solution here and link the tutorial as the source...

Comment: Especially considering all links are invalid now.

Answer (score -4):

[Rootstheme](http://www.rootstheme.com) (which is based on Twitter Bootstrap) has a really elegant way of loading scripts depending on the page/post type as seen in the **roots_scripts** function [which can be seen here on github](https://github.com/retlehs/roots/blob/master/lib/scripts.php).

Basically register all your scripts and styles then have conditional statements that wrap your **wp_enqueue_script** or **wp_enqueue_style** statements.