# Do WordPress Core Filenames Work as Hooks?

Tags: hooks, filesystem

This is in reference to [another answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/34897/21097) here on wordpress.stackexchange. The answerer used the filename as the hook to enqueue scripts and styles to certain pages.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'portfolio_admin_script', 11 );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'portfolio_admin_script', 11 );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is 'yes'.

Taken from [this article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/tips-articles/quick-tip-get-the-current-screens-hooks/) the suffix of those 'screen specific hooks' is given by:

- For custom admin pages added via `add_menu_page()` - including settings pages - (and related functions) it is the screen ID (the value returned by `add_menu_page()`)
- For the admin page listing posts of any post type, it is `edit.php`
- On the ‘add new’ page of any post type, it is `post-new.php`
- On the edit page of any post type, it is `post.php`
- For taxonomy pages it is `edit-tags.php`

You may find [this plug-in](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/current-admin-info) useful, developed by @Kaiser, based on the article linked to above.

Comment: You know how to get upvotes ;) - Note for later readers: The plugin was based on a concept developed by @StephenHarris.

Comment: If you look at the source of any admin page there is a a little bit of Javascript near the top that reveals those hook names, or enough of them that you can work out the rest, and a few other things.