# Hook when adding or editing a specific custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

I'd like to insert a script and if possible some PHP for a custom post type. I'm looking for a hook to do this on the add new or edit screens. Any idea what I'd use for this? I tried "edit_post" but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load a script just to custom post type in admin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34894/load-a-script-just-to-custom-post-type-in-admin)

Comment: That's helpful but it's not just scripts I want to load, but PHP as well if possible.

Comment: I did the same mistake as @Howdy_McGee with his duplicate suggestion with my answer. You probably should specify your question, but reading beforehand [How do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) won't hurt.

Comment: There are numerous hooks that will allow you to add PHP to a page, but without knowing where exactly you want to add the code your question can't really be answered with any specificity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`admin_enqueue_scripts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts):

> `admin_enqueue_scripts` is the first action hooked into the admin scripts actions. This hook provides a single parameter, the `$hook_suffix` for the current admin page. And it's an action it can only be used to callback a specified function.

Usage like:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name' );
```

The codex page provides even an example on how to target a specific admin page:

```
function wpse162680_enqueue_script( $hook ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $hook == 'post.php' && $screen->post_type != 'your-custom-posttype' ) {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myscript.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse162680_enqueue_script' );
```

Read [Admin Screen Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Admin_Screen_Reference) on how to target the right screen.

---

Note: About the other part of your question, maybe [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) will help to there, but actually I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: This might work, is there a way to target a specific post type?

Comment: You can test the current screen id against the post type slug, e.g. `if ( 'post_type_slug' == get_current_screen()->id ) { ... }`

Comment: I adapted my answer to help you out, but note this is only for scripts too.

Comment: Or as @DrewAPicture said, btw DrewAPicture you're right about your edit, this means the codex page is wrong ;) Do you want to update the codex or should I?

Comment: Going over there I've seen you did it already :) @DrewAPicture

Comment: Actually, I'm also updating the [Code Reference article](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/), which the Codex article will soon redirect to :)

Comment: Great, even better! I really like the new [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/). @DrewAPicture